# Azure Spatial Anchors (ASA) Cant find anchors when reconnecting to Azure session

Tags: azure, augmented-reality, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

When I try to find Azure Spatial Anchors after reconnecting to the session nothing happens. But finding the spatial anchors without disconnecting to the session seems to find the anchors. Am I misunderstanding how Azure sessions work?

Does starting an Azure session mean that I am starting a new session that deletes itself after I stop the application?

I am currently following the tutorial from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-spatial-anchors-tutorials/3-exercise-get-started-with-azure-spatial-anchors). I am quite new to HoloLens development so any help would be much appreciated

I have tried looking at other tutorials and pages but it doesn't seem to address this issue. [Tutorial Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-01)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Spatial anchors are persistent and they do get saved in Azure. When you stop the session and the watcher, you lose those Anchor IDs. You need to save the Anchor ID somewhere either locally or in a Azure Cosmos DB for later use (locate/update/delete).

This is explained in [Tutorial: Share spatial anchors across sessions and devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-share-anchors-across-devices?tabs=azure-portal%2CVS%2CUnityHoloLens) and [Tutorial: Sharing Azure Spatial Anchors across sessions and devices with an Azure Cosmos DB back end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/tutorials/tutorial-use-cosmos-db-to-store-anchors)